# How do I force the '+' sign before positive floats when using the format! macro?

Tags: rust, string-formatting

I'd like to have right-aligned floating-point number formatted by the `format!` macro with the sign always visible. Using the [syntax specification](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#syntax) I devised the following formatting:

```
format!("{:>10+.1}", 23.3434);
```

However I got compilation error:

```
error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'+'`
 --> src/main.rs:2:21
  |
2 |     let x = format!("{:>10+.1}", 23.3434);
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm using Rust 1.25.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specification clearly gives the order `[[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]` with:

```
align := '<' | '^' | '>'
sign := '+' | '-'
```

Therefore you cannot have a number between `>` and `+` and the width goes after the sign:

```
format!("{:>10+.1}", 23.3434);
```

This renders as `"     +23.3"`. Whereas:

```
format!("{:>+010.1}", 23.3434);
```

renders as `+0000023.3`.

Although, for maintainability, I would suggest using

```
format!("{:>+0width$.prec$}", 23.3434, width=10, prec=1);
```

Comment: Thank you. The documentation is not clear regarding placement of align width. The code `format!("{:>+10.1}", 23.3434)` worked.

Comment: I have opened [a PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/51067) to make some improvements, fell free to comment there about what could be improved further!